# How to install Ubuntu One Indicator in 12.10?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 12.10

I am trying to install the Ubuntu One indicator on Ubuntu 12.10.
I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rye/ubuntuone-extras
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-ubuntuone
```

And I get: E: `Unable to locate package indicator-ubuntuone`

Does anyone knows how to install it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to install the **indicator-sync** package. simply run

```
aptitude install indicator-sync
```

it should be in Ubuntus repositories.

the repository you have added is not the official indicator for ubuntuone but an alternative to it. Sadly there is no Ubuntu 12.10 port for it, thats why you can't find the package **indicator-ubuntuone**

Comment: from the software center?

Comment: you can use the software center as well, just search for indicator-sync, it'll have the description "Indicator for synchronisation processes status"

Answer (score 1):

Your commands are alright, they are working now. They did not work when you asked the question because indicator-ubuntuone packages for 12.10 had not been yet ready.

Comment: The OP is asking "How to" install not if there is one.  Can you add the "how to instructions" to your answer.

Comment: The instructions are given in the answer, they work, I can include them in this answer, but it is a bit pointless. I reworded my answer.